# how do i use list for selenium web driver in java

Tags: selenium, selenium2, java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

how do i use list for selenium web driver in java

I need to select id which are continuously changing, and one id is in one row.

need to select id from each

Edit :

```
 <tr id="tr-132885-id" class="bgwhite" onmouseout="hilightOnMouseOver('tr-132885-id','out')" onmouseover="hilightOnMouseOver('tr-132885-id','in')"> 
      <td class="companynm-td" valign="top"> <div id="expand-132885-div" class="left" style="vertical-align:top;"> 
         <a onclick="expandCompanyDetail('185159','132885','show','current','1');return false;" href="#">
```

Comment: paste yours html code we try to answer

Comment: This question doesn't clearly reflect what you are trying to ask. Please add more details

Comment: It can be done easily by xpath (by position). But we need to see your HTML and also if you have any tried any code so far??

Comment: I guess id is dynamic which gets changed everytime,you need to get the pattern of the id, and iterate over it

Comment: yes ID is dynamic which are changing for each row

Comment: <tr id="tr-132885-id" class="bgwhite" onmouseout="hilightOnMouseOver('tr-132885-id','out')" onmouseover="hilightOnMouseOver('tr-132885-id','in')">
<td class="companynm-td" valign="top">
<div id="expand-132885-div" class="left" style="vertical-align:top;">
<a onclick="expandCompanyDetail('185159','132885','show','current','1');return false;" href="#">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a way to list URLs, you can change the `By.tagName` to your required selector like `By.id`

```
WebDriver driver = FirefoxDriver();   
driver.get("www.google.com");
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Ask your developers to add a name (which does not need to be unique) to relevant elements. find_elements (Java may have different spelling) returns a LIST of elements.

If you cannot have name, you can find by CSS class. Xpath is locator of last hope, too brittle and too slow.

Comment: Yes! If locating an element is that difficult, its better to ask the developers to put unique, static and less fragile attributes to locate the element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store each and every ID from all of the rows or columns then look at the below code :

Step1: grab the table,
Step2: grab the rows,
Step3: grab the columns.

```
WebElement table=driver.findElement(By.id("someID"));
//you can choose id,xpath or any other unique locator.
List<WebElement> rowID=table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for(WebElement row:rowID){
    List<WebElement> colID=row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
}
```

now colID and rowID contains ID's of columns and rows respectively.